# Infinite loop(?) while trying to enqueue instance of user-defined class into queue

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue, doubly-linked-list

So I have a doubly-linked-list implementation of a Queue class (see below)
This queue class works perfectly fine when I try to enqueue ints and strings, but for some reason, when I try to enqueue a custom class, my program never moves past the line where `enqueue()` is called in main. I think it might be an infinite loop but I'm not sure. Short story short, why does my `enqueue()` method work for basic data types like int, char, & string, but not for custom classes?

Here's my queue class...

```
//
//  queue.h
//  
//
//  Created by Aaron Mamparo on 2/22/13.
//
//

#ifndef _queue_h
#define _queue_h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class Node {
public:
    Type elem;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node() {}
    Type Elem() { return elem; }
    Node* Next() { return next; }
    Node* Prev() { return prev; }
};

template<class Type>
class Queue {
    Node<Type> *head;
    Node<Type> *tail;
public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    bool isEmpty();
    int size();
    void enqueue(Type);
    Type dequeue();
    Node<Type>* at(int);
    Type get(int);
};

//default constructor
template<class Type>
Queue<Type>::Queue(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

//destructor
template<class Type>
Queue<Type>::~Queue(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        while(head){
            Node<Type> *del = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete[] del;
        }
    }
}

//return true if queue is empty
template<class Type>
bool Queue<Type>::isEmpty(){
    return head == NULL;
}

//return number of elems in queue
template<class Type>
int Queue<Type>::size(){
    int count = 0;
    Node<Type> *temp = head;
    while(temp){
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    delete temp;
    return count;
}

//insert elem to back of queue
template<class Type>
void Queue<Type>::enqueue(Type T){
    Node<Type> *newNode = new Node<Type>();
    newNode->elem = T;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = tail = newNode;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
    } else {
        newNode->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

//remove elem from front of queue
template<class Type>
Type Queue<Type>::dequeue(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        cerr << "Error: trying to dequeue from empty queue" << endl;
    } else {
        Type ret = head->Elem();
        Node<Type> *del = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete del;
        return ret;
    }
}

//return a pointer to element at position i
template<class Type>
Node<Type>* Queue<Type>::at(int i){
    if(isEmpty()){
        return '\0';
    } else if (i>size()-1){
        return NULL;
    } else {
        Node<Type> *temp = new Node<Type>();
        temp = head;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

//remove & return element at position i
template<class Type>
Type Queue<Type>::get(int i){
    if(isEmpty()){
        return NULL;
    } else if (i>size()-1){
        return NULL;
    } else {
        Node<Type> *temp = new Node<Type>();
        temp = head;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
        Type ret = temp->Elem();
        delete temp;
        return ret;
    }
}
#endif
```

and my driver in main that won't go past `stateQueue.enqueue(state);`

```
int main() {
    Queue<State> stateQueue;
    State newState = readInput();    //'readInput()' returns an instance of 'State'
    stateQueue.enqueue(newState);

    cout << "DONE" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in the above code, "DONE" is never displayed...
I know for sure that `readInput()` isn't the problem since "DONE" prints when I insert it before the `.enqueue()` call...
Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: here's the default constructor, copy constructor, destructor, and overloaded assignment operator for my `State` class...

```
State::State(){
    pieces = Queue<Piece>();
    stateHistory = Queue<string>();
    moveHistory = Queue<string>();
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

//copy constructor
State::State(const State& rhs){
    pieces = rhs.pieces;
    stateHistory = rhs.stateHistory;
    moveHistory = rhs.moveHistory;
    rows = rhs.rows;
    cols = rhs.cols;
}

//destructor
State::~State(){
}

//overloaded assignment operator
State& State::operator=(const State &rhs){
    pieces = rhs.pieces;
    stateHistory = rhs.stateHistory;
    moveHistory = rhs.moveHistory;
    rows = rhs.rows;
    cols = rhs.cols;
    return *this;
}
```

EDIT: here's a copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator I just implemented...

```
template<class Type>
Queue<Type>::Queue(const Queue<Type>&Q)
{
    *this = Q;
}

template<class Type>
Queue<Type>& Queue<Type>::operator=(const Queue<Type> &Q)
{
    head = Q.head;
    tail = Q.tail;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried stepping through many times but can't figure out the problem... I'm gonna set a breakpoint and step-through again so I can tell you exactly where it stops, give me a minute..

Comment: If it works until you try to use your custom class, there is likely a flaw in your custom class.  Probably involving default-construction or assignment.

Comment: Well... I set a breakpoint at enqueue() within queue.h
And I stepped through it as it processed `newState`, and it stepped all the way through to the end of the method just fine... but when I stepped back out into main, the debugger arrow that told me which line the program's on was gone, and I have no clue why...

Comment: okay, I just added a snippet of code from my `State` class... but I still don't see what could cause this..

Comment: There is one problem in the Queue destructor: `delete[] del;` which assumes that `del` points to an array (allocated by `new[]`), but it points to single node.

Comment: okay, but when I remove the `[]` I get the following error...

`malloc: *** error for object 0x100103b80: pointer being freed was not allocated`

How should I modify the destructor so that it deletes the head?
Also, should I included an overloaded assignment operator in my queue class?

Comment: You do not need to modify Queue destructor after you removed[] from delete, it should be fine, problem is in State destructor, not in Queue

Comment: I'm new to C++ programming, so I'm not totally familiar with how to use destructors... do I just delete all members of the instance of `State`?

Comment: In this case you actually did not have to provide copy constructor and assignment operator of State, compiler generated would be sufficient. What you need is proper copy constructor and assignment operator of Queue.

Answer (score 0):

> Short story short, why does my enqueue() method work for basic data types like int, char, & string, but not for custom classes?

It is difficult to say for sure as you did not provide details of State class, but problem seems to be there, you have a raw pointer or something and do not implement proper assignment operator, which you use in your Queue::enqueue() method:

```
newNode->elem = T;
```

PS you added State implementation (not definition though) but it shows that it uses Queue class itself inside. State assignment uses compiler generated assignment operator of Queue, but Queue class has raw pointers, so you get double deletion of head pointer.

One possible solution is to store pointer to object inside your queue, instead of object itself:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<State> StatePtr;
int main() {
    Queue<StatePtr> stateQueue;
    StatePtr newState = readInput();    //'readInput()' now returns a smart pointer to 'State'
    stateQueue.enqueue(newState);

    cout << "DONE" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you will need to change readInput() accordingly.
Also I would recommend to prohibit copying and assigning Queue object, so compiler would help you to prevent problems like this.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're getting at... but how do I get around this? I'm sorry about all the questions... I'm a c++ n00b

Comment: Implement proper copy constructor and assignment operator for Queue

Comment: ok, I updated the original post with the copy constructor and assignment operator I implemented... but it still won't work

Comment: That's not proper implementation, that does exactly what compiler generated did before. Another solution would be not to copy State but pass a smart pointer to it.

Comment: I still don't completely understand the solution you're proposing... should I re-implement my queue class to store pointers instead of nodes?

Comment: You do not need to reimplement your queue class to store pointer, look into my updated answer